# Energy Density Confusion

Tags: electrostatics

The energy density of an electromagnetic field with a linear dielectric is often expressed as $0.5 E \cdot D$. It is also known that energy can be found by $\int_{V} \rho V dV$. Using the latter, the energy density is found to be $0.5 E^2 \varepsilon_0$, as is well known. If you integrate the latter only over free charge and ignore bound charge, you write $\epsilon \nabla \cdot E=     \rho$, use integration by parts, and obtain the first result. Does the first result neglect the energy from bound charge? If not, why does $0.5 E^2 \varepsilon_0$ break down (I.e. why can’t one find the energy with a dielectric by treating the bound charge as its own independent charge arrangement and using formulae for a vacuum?)